# Will removing a promotional site with little traffic from my main domain and moving my sub-domain blog there affect SEO?

Tags: seo, subdomain, blog, site-move

I have a blog under a sub-domain, let's say it's `test.example.com`. I want to move all my sub-domain content to my main domain `example.com` and delete my sub-domain. How much will this affect my SEO rankings? And how can I minimize the amount it gets affected?

Comment: What do you have on the main domain now?   You say you want to "delete" the sub-domain.  What does that mean?  For SEO you would generally have to leave it in place and redirect it.

Comment: On my main domain I just have a promotional website and I have a blog on my sub-domain, I want to move the blog to my main domain. So would I have to not delete my sub-domain and just redirect to my main domain when a user visits it? @StephenOstermiller

Comment: So what is going to happen to the promotional website?

Comment: Well I don't really get much traffic there, I get more traffic on the blog so I was just thinking of deleting the promotional site and replacing it with the blog. @StephenOstermiller

Comment: When you move text to the primary domain, the search engines index it as new content for the primary domain - example.com.

Comment: Ahh ok, I see. What I'm mostly concerned with is organic searches. Right now if I google the name of one of my blog posts it shows up on the results, I'm worried that if I move the blog to my main domain and search for a post it wont show up on the results.

Answer (score 1):

If you manage redirection properly then you should be fine.

Move your blog (test.example.com) to example.com.

Once this is done then just redirect your sub-domain pages to respective pages on the website.

**Example:**

Old Blog:
test.example.com => Blog

test.example.com/blog-page1 => Blog Page

etc.

Once this is moved to example.com then you should have pages on your main domain like:

example.com/blog-page1

Now, with regards to redirection (301), depending on your server type you may be able to redirection at sub domain level. So any sub domain page will automatically get redirected to a respective page on the main website. If this may be hard then you can do individual redirection.

Comment: I'm using Apache as my web server, so can I use an .htaccess file for redirection? If so can you give me an example of what it should look like... Keep in mind I have many routes in my sub-domain. For example, `test.example.com` should redirect to `example.com`, `test.example.com/blog` should redirect to `example.com/blog` and `test.example.com/blog/my-blog-post` should redirect to `example.com/blog/my-blog-post` and so on...